# String Palindrome

Tags: c++, string, recursion, palindrome

When am trying to run this code, am getting the opposite output. Please let me know, what am doing wrong...

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool ps(string s,int l, int r){
    if(l>=r) 
        return true;
    if(s[l]!=s[r])
        return false;
    return ps(s,++l,--r);
}
 
int main(){
    string str="naman";
    int s=str.size();
    bool b=ps(str,0,s);
    if(!b){
        cout<<"Not a plaindrome";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"A plaindrome";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inputting the wrong starting value to `ps`. The line

```
bool b=ps(str,0,s);
```

should be

```
bool b=ps(str,0,s - 1);
```

as the last character in a string is at index `string.size() - 1` not `string.size()`

Comment: Note that to realise this was where the issue was I added a print statement to the top of `ps` to see how far it got (`cout << "l " << l << " r  << r << endl`) Adding statements like these or using a debugger is how you can solve issues like this for yourself in future.